# Easiest way to write to a SQL table with python

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, pyodbc

I am looking for a simple and easy to understand way to write into an SQL table in a database. 
I tried a couple of different ways but still get some errors and don't really know how to interpret them.
In my case, I try to write a pandas dataframe, but it could also be 2D numpy array.
My current approach is as follows:

```
# Import libraries:
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

# In this example, a pandas dataframe is created as below:
cols = ['key1', 'locationKey', 'locationGroupKey', 'dayType', 'effectiveFromDate', 'effectiveToDate', 'prctAM0', 'prctAM1', 'prctAM2', 'prctPM0', 'prctPM1', 'prctPM2', 'prctEV0', 'prctEV1', 'prctEV02', 'prctAD']
values = [[178,10218,0,'2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00',.33,0,0,.33,0,0,.33,0,0,0],                
        [178,10218,0,'2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00',.33,0,0,.33,0,0,.33,0,0,0],
        [178,10218,0,'2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00','2018-06-06 00:00:00',.33,0,0,.33,0,0,.33,0,0,0],]
df = DataFrame(values, columns = cols)

# Create connection:
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServername;DATABASE=myDBname;UID=fieldReadUser;PWD=myPW')
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

# Write into SQL table:
df.to_sql('tbl_Interval, schema='dbo', con=engine, if_exists='append', index = False)
```

EDIT: With the suggestions listed below, the code is writing into the table now.

Comment: `int is incompatible with text`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I tried replacing the strings in my dataframe with integers and also converting all dataframe elements into strings (in case the database only accepts strings. Both still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `to_sql` is *just* the table name. If you need to specify the schema then you supply it separately as `schema=`, e.g.,

```
df.to_sql('tbl_Interval', engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this brought me a little bit further. I updated the post, there is still an 'invalid column name 'index'' which I believe is the index from the pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Hendrik then set `index=False`

Comment: @Hendrik - As suggested by mad_ I have updated the answer.